# port protocol, os, device type and services running

Tags: c#, port, protocols

I have a port scanner that creates a integer and tests if the port is open on a host,  with this integer I would like to find the protocol of the port (https, pop3, ssh and any others).

Also I would like to find the os, device type, and the services that are running on the host that is being scanned.

How do I find the protocol of the port and os, device type, and the services that are running on the host?

thanks.

Comment: Ok, so - is there a question? You do know what question is, right? Do not tell us what you want to do - ask questions.

Comment: _"How to create a port scanner and network inventory tool"_ is offtopic for SO. It's way too broad. Tools already exist for this, if you want to re-invent the wheel that's fine - you just can't come here to ask us to write it for you. Please try to ask a specific question.